# In flutter web Odia language show strange character

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, flutter-web-browser

In my project utf8 is already set in web.This happen only for odia language. I am using Text widget to show the text.

Text Widget :

Text("କାନାରା ଏଚଏସବିସି ଲାଇଫ୍ ଇନସୁରାନ୍ସ କମ୍ପାନୀ ଲିମିଟେଡ୍"),

[image: Odia language show strange charachter]

Comment: What font are you using? This only happens when you run in web?

Comment: yes this happen only in web if try to run in web using canvaskit. it show strange characters.